# find the records which are coming in both files

Tags: shell

I want to find out the intersect records which are coming in both files. limitation is that records can appear in any position in the files. for that i am using below piece of code

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}($0 in a)' 1.txt 2.txt
```

but is is not working correctly.

Suppose I have two files 1.txt and 2.txt.

1.txt

```
A
B
D
E
```

2.txt

```
DD
T
B
A
Z
```

OUPUT should be like this

```
B
A
```

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
grep -w -f 1.txt 2.txt
```

-w states for word

-f states for file

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

use `comm` command, that's the the purpose of this command:

```
comm <(sort 1.txt)  <( sort 2.txt) -12
```

from `man comm`:

```
With no options, produce three-column output.  Column one contains lines
unique to FILE1, column two contains lines unique to FILE2, and column
three contains lines common to both files.

-1     suppress column 1 (lines unique to FILE1)
-2     suppress column 2 (lines unique to FILE2)
-3     suppress column 3 (lines that appear in both files)
```

However, `comm` requires sorted files. Hence the process substitution, as `<(sort 1.txt)` & `<(sort 2.txt)`